# Keep form values after validation in struts 1.2

Tags: java, struts, validation

Hi i am building a webapp with struts 1.2

I am building an "edit" form, so i have my input tags being pre populated from a bean:

form.jsp

```
<html:text property="population"
value="${city.population}"/>
```

Later on, i use struts validation

The problem is, i have 10 form elements, if one of them fails by the validation rules, the action gets back to the form and populates de elements with the bean data and not with the resently changed data of the user.

I wan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the `value` attribute you have there. The `property` attribute should be enough to show the correct value in the input. Having `value` there will always cause the value of `${city.population}` to be displayed.

Comment: ¿How can i populate this element without using value?

Comment: It would be populated when the form is submitted. If it needs to be pre-populated when the page is displayed for the first time, you should set the values on the `ActionForm` in your `Action`.